# How to dynamically add a column and fill the newly added column with data in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have first created a Jtable(thru netbeans GUI) with single column and 6 rows (empty column). Next I have added a column dynamically using the following command

```
summaryTableForVAriousSm.getColumnModel().addColumn(new TableColumn());
```

While running the application I can see that the column is created dynamically. So I felt like adding data to the newly created column using the command

```
summaryTableForVAriousSm.setValueAt("1000", 1, 1);
```

(similarly for all other 6 rows filling column wise)
This change is also reflected in the running of application, but the problem here is the data inserted in the newly created column is also being overridden in the column 0 (if any data is present). why the changes in one column are being reflected in the other column. Also how can keep them separate, so that changes in one columns doesn't affect data in other column.

Comment: you have to add the column on the tableModel (not the tableColumnModel - that's done automatically)

Comment: what you are saying is i have to use summaryTableForVAriousSm.getModel() to add the new column. But there doesnt exist a method for adding column through table model. can u please post an example

Answer (score 3):

The reason the data is set to the first column is that both columns are mapped to the same column in the underlying model. See the api doc for TableColumn():

> using a default **model index** of 0, default width of 75, a null renderer and a null editor

(bolding by me)

Now the table's setValueAt is in view coordinates, that are internally converted to model coordinates. For columns basically  by querying its modelIndex:

```
// in JTable.setValueAt
int modelColumnIndex = getColumnModel().getColumn(viewColumn).getModelIndex()
```

Assuming the underlying model is a DefaultTableModel

```
((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addColumn(somename);
```

Comment: i know the first point you mentioned. So how can i now create a column without any reference to already existing column. Once created, how to add data to the new column. Can you please explain in detail

Comment: there are no more details - simply replace your column adding with the last line and be happy :-) Or use any of the other column adding methods in the _TableModel_, either DefaultTM or a custom model which supports adding columns dynamically.

Comment: adding a column is not a problem. But the way of adding a column dynamically should not be a reference of first column already existing. Because of which data modified in any of the columns is reflecting in both the columns. I need an independent column without any reference with the first column

Comment: Repeating: you have to add the column to the **TableModel** (not the TableColumnModel nor the the JTable). Anyway, be sure you read and understand the chapter _How to use JTable_ in the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki.