# Insert Column into a JTable through DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, jtable, addition, defaulttablemodel, tablecolumn

I have a problem with redrawing the table after model changed.

I'm writing a table model class extended by DefaulTableModel.
I have written a function named "addColumn", which will be used for adding a Column to the JTable in runtime.
When I make the modification on the dataVector in the model, I call the fireTableStructureChanged() function, but its ineffective.

I have written a function named removeColumnAt(int n), which is used to remove the nth Column from the JTable where I also use the dataVector and the fireTableStructureChanged()function and it works well.

[1st part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HopNG.png)

[2st part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcPgr.png)

Comment: What's wrong with `DefaultTableModel::addColumn`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12816206/230513)? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], not pictures of code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the answer.

I have accidentally called an addColumn before adding the element and that was the source of the problem